# Regular Expression Match lines that start with a space character

Tags: php, regex, search

```
3.2 Mark one answer
You must NOT sound your horn
 between 10 pm and 6 am in a built-up
area
 at any time in a built-up area
 between 11.30 pm and 7 am in a builtup
area
 between 11.30 pm and 6 am on any
road
Vehicles can be noisy. Every effort must be
made to prevent excessive noise, especially
in built-up areas at night. Don’t
```

Regex

```
/^ ([\w-,@\.?:=+&%$£@"'’\s ]+)/gmi
```

Running the regex above does not produce any results. I want the lines

I want the options as

```
between 10 pm and 6 am in a built-up
area

at any time in a built-up area

between 11.30 pm and 7 am in a builtup
area

between 11.30 pm and 6 am on any
road
```

Comment: Try [`^\h[\w-,@\.?:=+&%$£@"'’\h ]+[\r\n]*[a-z].*`](https://regex101.com/r/qR5bT5/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with `preg_match_all` function. 
(I want to thank Wiktor Stribiżew for reminding me about horizontal/vertical whitespace characters `\h`, `\v`)

```
$text = "3.2 Mark one answer
You must NOT sound your horn
 between 10 pm and 6 am in a built-up
area
 at any time in a built-up area
 between 11.30 pm and 7 am in a builtup
area
 between 11.30 pm and 6 am on any
road
Vehicles can be noisy. Every effort must be
made to prevent excessive noise, especially
in built-up areas at night. Don’t";

preg_match_all("/^\h{1}.+?[\r\n]{1}(\H*?\b(?=[\r\n]{1}))?/im", $text, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($matches[0]);

// the output:
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(43) " between 10 pm and 6 am in a built-up
area
"
  [1]=>
  string(32) " at any time in a built-up area
"
  [2]=>
  string(45) " between 11.30 pm and 7 am in a builtup
area
"
  [3]=>
  string(39) " between 11.30 pm and 6 am on any
road
"
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question @RomanPerekhrest - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940431/regular-expression-is-not-outputting-all-the-potential-matches-in-php

Answer (score 1):

If you really just need all lines starting with a single space character you can use this simple regex:

```
/^ (.*)$/gm
```

Explanation:

```
- "/" = Start of regular expression
- "^" = Match beginning of line
- " " = Match one space character
- "(.*)" = Match any sequence of characters and remember match
- "$" = regex ends at end of line
- "/" = End of regular expression
- gm = match [g]lobally and treat string as [m]ultiple lines
```

Without modifier "m" the character "^" would match the start of the string and "$" would match the end of the string.