# Regular expression is not outputting all the potential matches in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Take a look at the regex located at:

https://regex101.com/r/hC3uJ7/1

When I run this regex on PHP I am only getting the first lines instead of the full content of the outer bracket. Can someone please help me solve this problem.

[image]

Result
[image]

The issue I am facing is that when I run the same code in php, the only matches I get are:

[image]

Comment: You just need to go to *code generator* page at regex101.com and grab the code there. See [the demo](https://ideone.com/wYYVW9).

Comment: How did you convert the text to get \n in the lines ? That is my issue.

Comment: Replace `\n` in your regex with `\R`. Perhaps, your line breaks are CRLF, not just LF. Try `^[^\w\s] ([\w-,@\.\?\(\)\*!;:=+&%$£@"'’ ]*(\R[a-z-,@\.\?\(\)\*!;:=+&%$£@"'’][\w-,@\.\?\(\)\*!;:=+&%$£@"'’ ]+)*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that *"code generator"* on *regex101.com* does not escaping some characters, in particular - `$` symbol.
Considering the above fact, you'll get the desired result:

```
$re = "/^[^\\w\\s] ([\\w-,@\\.\\?\\(\\)\\*!;:=+&%\$£@\"'’ ]*(\\n[a-z-,@\\.\\?\\(\\)\\*!;:=+&%\$£@\"'’][\\w-,@\\.\\?\\(\\)\\*!;:=+&%\$£@\"'’ ]+)*)/mu";
$str = "1.37 Mark one answer\nYou must not use a hand-held phone while\ndriving. Using a hands-free system\n is acceptable  in a vehicle with power\nsteering fljsadlfkjasldkfjlaksd lkfjasld\nlfksadjflkasjdflaksjdfalks lkfj sdlk\n will significantly reduce your field of\nvision\n will affect your vehicle's electronic\nsystems\n is still likely to distract your attention\nfrom the road\nWhile driving your concentration is required\nall the time. Even using a hands-free kit can\nstill distract your attention from the road.\nAny distraction, however brief, is potentially\ndangerous and could cause you to lose\ncontrol. Except in a genuine emergency, it\nis an offence to u";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($matches[0]);

// the output:
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(118) " is acceptable  in a vehicle with power
steering fljsadlfkjasldkfjlaksd lkfjasld
lfksadjflkasjdflaksjdfalks lkfj sdlk"
  [1]=>
  string(48) " will significantly reduce your field of
vision"
  [2]=>
  string(47) " will affect your vehicle's electronic
systems"
  [3]=>
  string(58) " is still likely to distract your attention
from the road"
}
```

Comment: I get empty array in var dump for the exact code above.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5, the above code works perfectly for me. I think the problem might be in some characters encoding (utf-8). Add `u` modifier to the regex pattern (see my update)

Comment: I am getting the text from the text area instead of putting it directly in the variable in php (in that case it does work). But I am trying to get data form the text area in a post request and it doesn't work then.

Comment: posted textarea likely contains line breaks in such form `"\r\n"` or `\n\r`. So, try to replace all possible forms into "`\n`" beforehand. Example: `$str = str_replace(["\r\n", "\n\r"],"\n", $textarea_content);`